# Add SecWebSocketProtocol header (SubProtocol) to WebSocketHandler in ASP Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, websocket

In `ASP Web API`, upgrading to `WebSocket` requires initialization of Microsoft.Web.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler. This type of`WebSocket` doesn't give the option to add a SecWebSocketProtocol header, which is essential for my case (`MQTT` over `WebSockets`).

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.IsWebSocketRequest || HttpContext.Current.IsWebSocketRequestUpgrading)
    {
       HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new WebSocketHandler());
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
    }

    else return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

How can I add this field to the WebSocketHandler?

Comment: `HttpContext` has the signature  `AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task> userFunc);`. Your example is not compiling.

Comment: No it has an overload that also accepts Microsoft.Web.WebSocket.WebSocketHandler